# Is get_rect a list, and how can I get it's components?

Tags: text, pygame, pygame-surface

I'm rendering some text on a screen and I want to draw a box behind acting as background. Text is a surface if I know correctly, so you call get_rect() to get it's coordinates, width and height.
So when I print(my_text_surface.get_rect()) I get this:

> ```
> rect(0, 0, 382, 66)>
> ```

By this information I assume I can write:

```
my_suface.get_rect(1)
```

and get it's x coordinate. But then it's says:

get_rect only accepts keyword arguments

So I'm asking you here if get_rect() can get me a list and, if yes how can I access it?

If you need my code:

```
font = self.pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 64)

spadenpala_text = font.render("Spadenpala", True, (255, 255, 255))
spadenpala_text_position = spadenpala_text.get_rect(center=(self.width/2, 200))
print(spadenpala_text.get_rect([1]))
```

Thanks, Mirko Dolenc

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally posted the question before it was complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pygame.Surface.get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) doesn't return a list, but a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object:

> Returns a new rectangle covering the entire surface.

[`pygame.Surface.get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) returns a rectangle with the size of the *Surface* object, that always starts at (0, 0) since a *Surface* object has no position. A *Surface* is `blit` at a position on the screen. The position of the rectangle can be specified by a keyword argument. For example, the center of the rectangle can be specified with the keyword argument `center`. These keyword argument are applied to the attributes of the [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) before it is returned (see [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) for a full list of the keyword arguments).
A `pygame.Rect` object has a lot of virtual attributes like `.x`, `.y`, `.width`, `.height` etc. e.g.:

```py
surf = pygame.Surface((100, 50))
rect = surf.get_rect(center = (200, 200))
print(rect)
print(rect.x)
print(rect.y)
print(rect.width)
print(rect.height)
```

output:

```
<rect(150, 175, 100, 50)>
150
175
100
50
```